# Был почитаемым или почитаем?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Он был почитаемым среди народа. Или ПОЧИТАЕМ?

Comment: «В народе»... Среди людей, среди народов... Среди — подразумевает множество, а народ представляет собой некое единство.

Comment: Спасибо! Исправлю.

Comment: У Платонова есть рассказ "Среди народа".

Comment: "Среди народа" — 216 вхождений в Нацкорпусе. Хотя звучит как пришедшее из "старины глубокой".

Comment: Для народа специально был составлен «Пролог», известный на Руси уже с XII века; среди народа широкое хождение получили апокрифы. [С. А. Еремеева. Лекции по русскому искусству (2000)]

Comment: СРЕДИ ЗДЕСЬ – в этом месте; в данном обществе ( "Большой полутолковый словарь одесского языка", 2002 г.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Нацкорпусе 14 вхождений "был почитаем" и ни одного "был почитаемым"

> И прошла молва об Иисусе, и он был почитаем всеми. [Л. Н. Толстой. Соединение и перевод четырех Евангелий (1902) // «Толстовский Листок - Запрещенный Толстой», №6, 1995]